# Content filter does not search drupal7

Tags: drupal, filter, hook, admin

I have added a drop down of my courses title at the filter second of the drupal - admin - content area.

http://www.XYZ.com/demo/admin/content

But when I select any of the title and hit Filter nothing gets appear. The data which showed previously it shows again, nothing happens really.

My code for the add filter drop down:

```
function products_form_node_admin_content_alter(&$form, &$form_state){

$results = db_query("SELECT r.nid, r.title FROM {node} AS n 
                  LEFT JOIN {node_revision} AS r ON r.nid = n.nid
                  WHERE type = 'product'")->fetchAll(); 
$optionsF   =   Array ( '[any]' => 'any' ); 
foreach($results as $key => $result) {

    $options[$result->title]    =   $result->title;
}
$options    =   $optionsF + $options;

$course_titles['title'] = Array
    (
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#options' => $options,
        '#title' => 'title',
        '#default_value' => 'any'
    );

$form['filter']['filters']['status']['filters'] = $form['filter']['filters']['status']['filters'] + $course_titles;     

$uid_column = array('uniqueid' => array(
    'data'  => 'UniqueID',
    'field' => 'n.nid'
));

$form['admin']['nodes']['#header'] = $form['admin']['nodes']['#header']+$uid_column;

foreach ($form['admin']['nodes']['#options'] as $key => $row) {     
    $node = node_load(array('nid' => check_plain($key)));                 
    $form['admin']['nodes']['#options'][$key]['uniqueid']   =   $node->field_unique_code_course['und'][0]['value'];
}
```

}

Does any body have any idea what is lacking in my code or method?

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Admin Views, it's built for this purpose.

https://drupal.org/project/admin_views